# How to get products category with name in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am getting product name sku price using following query but I want to fetch category also. How can I do this?

```
SET @etype = (SELECT entity_type_id
                FROM eav_entity_type
                WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product');
-- Product name attribute ID
SET @name = (SELECT attribute_id
        FROM eav_attribute
        WHERE attribute_code = 'name'
          AND entity_type_id = @etype);
-- Product image attribute ID
SET @image = (SELECT attribute_id
        FROM eav_attribute
        WHERE attribute_code = 'image'
          AND entity_type_id = @etype);
-- Product price attribute ID
SET @price = (SELECT attribute_id
        FROM eav_attribute
        WHERE attribute_code = 'price'
          AND entity_type_id = @etype);
-- Admin store ID
SET @store = 0;

-- Query
SELECT 
    e.entity_id AS 'id',
    e.sku,
    v1.value AS 'name',
    v2.value AS 'image',
    si.qty AS 'stock qty',
    d1.value AS 'price'

FROM catalog_product_entity e
        LEFT JOIN
    cataloginventory_stock_item si ON e.entity_id = si.product_id
        LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_varchar v1 ON e.entity_id = v1.entity_id
        AND v1.store_id = @store
        AND v1.attribute_id = @name
        LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_varchar v2 ON e.entity_id = v2.entity_id
        AND v2.store_id = @store
        AND v2.attribute_id = @image
        LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_decimal d1 ON e.entity_id = d1.entity_id
        AND d1.store_id = @store
        AND d1.attribute_id = @price;
```